# Attempting to format date month to full name returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I using the following code to try to convert the numerical month (5) to the full name (May). When I change the setting from MM to MMMM, however, it just returns null. Why is this?

```
NSDate *date = [birthday getDate];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [components year];

if (year == 1604) {
    NSString *monthNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components month]];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:monthNumberString];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString *monthDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %d", stringFromDate, [components day]];
    cell.birthdayLabel.text = monthDay;
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: And it works with `MM`?

Comment: Yes, MM returns "05", for May...

Comment: It is not working as DateFormatter expects it to be May, and you are passing 5. If the format is MM, formatter expects 5. As simple as that.

Comment: I see, so are you saying I am using the wrong code to turn 5 into May? Do you know what I should be using? Thank you for helping.

Comment: As you are always passing the month from components, it would be always in `MM` so you just need to use that format. That's it.

Comment: I did think that, but when I do that the result is still 5. Code is `NSString *monthDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, %d", [components month], [components day]];`

Comment: You can't expect an NSDateFormatter to create an NSDate from only a month.  There must, at minimum, be year/month/day or the result (from experience -- don't know that it's written down anywhere) is "undefined" and may be nil.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NSDate *date = [birthday getDate];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                               fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [components year];

if (year == 1604)
{
    NSString *monthNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components month]];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:monthNumberString];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSString *monthDay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %d", stringFromDate, [components day]];

    NSLog(@"%@",monthDay);

    cell.birthdayLabel.text = monthDay;
}
else {

}
```

Comment: There is way too much extra code and conversions going on here. See my answer for the simple approach.

Comment: @rmaddy You are rite, I just added a single line of code so that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the date. Just format it:

```
NSDate *date = [birthday getDate];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [components year];

if (year == 1604) {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM, d"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    cell.birthdayLabel.text = stringFromDate;
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: Though one wonders whether the individual in question worries about birthdays anymore.